# asp.net mvc if else not working in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

This is my part of code from view called `index`

```
  <div class="box-body">
                    @{ Html.RenderAction("_BlogsGrid",new {country=""});}
  </div>
  ...
  ...
<script>
    $("#SelectedCountry").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_BlogsGrid","Blog")' + '?country=' + selectedCountry,
            sucess: function(xhr, data) {
                console.log('sucess');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

    });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the controller action code

```
public ActionResult _BlogsGrid(string country)
{
    var blogs = _blogService.GetBlogWithCountryName(country).ToList();
    var blogsList = BlogMapper.ToBlogIndex(blogs);
    return PartialView(blogsList);
}
```

and here is **_BlogsGrid** view

```
@model  Blog.BlogsList
<div class="pull-right">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.CountriesList), "Select a country", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<br />
<br />
@if (Model.Blogs.Count == 0)
{
    <div class="box-group">
        <h4>Sorry we couldn't find any blog related to the country you asked for.</h4>
        @Html.DisplayText("Hello world!")
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="box-group" id="accordion">
        @foreach (var blog in Model.Blogs)
        {
            @*Some code*@
        }
    </div>
}
```

Thing is when i load it first time everything works fine, the controllers method gets hit and all the blogs get loaded this is how the view looks
[image]

but when I select a country from dropdown list and there are no blogs matching that country
[image]

it hits the if condition(putting a breakpoint in view I check if if condition is being executed or else condition is being executed, and it goes through if condition) in view (which is a partial view)
[image]
 but the content of "if" is not loaded in the browser.
I am still getting same content as before. Any idea why my content is not being updated?

**Update:**

```
 <div id="grid" class="box-body">
                        @{ Html.RenderAction("_BlogsGrid",new {country=""});}
 </div>

<script>
    $("#SelectedCountry").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_BlogsGrid","Blog")' + '?country=' + selectedCountry,
            sucess: function (data) {
                $('#grid').html(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

    });
    });
</script>
```

in browser response
[image]

But still my div is not updating.

Comment: I don't see any code that would update the content.  Your ajax call just does a `console.log` either way, not doing anything to update the page.

Comment: what are you doing inside  the ajax `sucess` callback. Is that the dummy code for this post or the actual code?

Comment: Your ajax function triggers when the element which id is "SelectedCountry" gets changed, which you forgot to put in your select tag parameters, so it should be written like `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.CountriesList), "Select a country", new { @class = "form-control", id = "SelectedCountry"  })`

Comment: @Tiramonium I don't need to put id, html.dropdownlistfor automatically does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others suggested, you're not updating your `div` content. That's way yo don't notice a change when the AJAX call is completed.

To ease things, in addition to `.ajax()`, jQuery provides the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, which automatically fed the returned content into the matched elements. So your javascript could look like so:

```
<script>
    $("#SelectedCountry").change(function () {
        var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
        $("div.box-body").load('@Url.Action("_BlogsGrid","Blog")', 'country=' + selectedCountry);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Cybercop There was a typo in my example. Did you copy/pasted it? I've corrected it now...

Answer (score 0):

When the page is created, Razor replace all `@` by their value to generated the **whole** HTML page. This is why in debug mode, your `@Html.DisplayText` is hit.

However, when you load the page, the `if` is taken into account, and if the condition is false, you don't see the inner HTML.

To update your DOM, you have to use the `data` parameter of the `success` ajax call. This parameter is automatically set by the return of your `_BlogsGrid` method.

You can see it by modifying your `success` callback. Note that the `data` parameter should be the first parameter

```
sucess: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 },
```

Comment: I don't get you. Else statement is not hit when count is 0. Anyways what do you suggest to update my content when count is 0 instead of having old content

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the data after the initial load. Your `ajax` call returns the html content of your partial view. You'd have to update it to the DOM manually. Give your container div an `id`.

```
<div id="blogs-grid" class="box-body">
     @{ Html.RenderAction("_BlogsGrid",new {country=""});}
 </div>
```

And then in your ajax success callback:

```
sucess: function(data) {
     $('#blogs-grid').html(data);
 },
```

Now whatever content your ajax returned will be bound to the `blogs-grid` div

Comment: I am not using data parameter in my ajax call. Maybe I need to have data parameter set so that I can get the content.

Comment: @Cybercop you have added it, but in the wrong order. The first parameter in the `ajax` success callback is the `data` returned from the server.

Comment: I did what you said but still it doesn't work. I can see in browser that i am getting some html response which is what i want but my div is not being updated. I will update my answer so you can see what is happening

Comment: I changed my ajax code to 
 sucess: function (data) {
                alert("hello");
                $('#grid').html(data);
            }, but the alert doesn't hit. So seems like my success method is not executing

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax success function does nothing with the server response. It just print success in the browser console.

You need to use the server response on the success function and replace the atual content of the page with the new content.

Your html response is the first argument from success function.
You can look at jquery documentantion for better undertanding (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

To replace the content of your page the success function should be like that:

```
sucess: function(data) {
            $("div.box-body").html(data);
            console.log('sucess');
        },
```